# I enabled Bitlocker on Win7 and now I can't boot Windows from Grub (Linux works). How to recover?

Tags: windows-7, linux, grub, bitlocker

I have a computer that was setup to dualboot between Win7 and Kali linux using Grub, which worked fine. Now I enabled Bitlocker on the Win7-partition and now it won't boot. The error message is `BOOTMGR is missing`.

I have read a couple of articles about this but they all describe what to BEFORE you enable Bitlocker.

How do I recover?

Clarification: I can start my computer and reach the Grub menu. If I select linux in the Grub menu it works fine but if I select Windows I get the error message described above.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.  I can't tell if you are indicating that Windows won't boot or Kali.  Linux does not typically like being on a BitLocker protected volume.  Native Linux support for BitLocker is extremely limited.

Comment: @Ramhound I can start my computer and reach the Grub menu. If I select linux in the Grub menu it works fine but if I select Windows I get the error message described above.

Comment: Your current question as it is currently written is not clear.  Instead of submitting a comment you should clarify your question by editing it.